# nav in header or after header?

Tags: html, markup

Hi I'm just wondering if there is a preferred standard for placing the main nav with in a page, either with in the header tag or after the closing header tag

```
<header>
    <div class="content">
        <a href="#" class="headerlogo"></a>
        <div class="headercontact">
            <ul class="headernumbers"></ul>
            <ul class="headersocial"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<nav id="mainnav">
    <ul class="nav content"></ul>
</nav>
```

or

```
<header>
    <div class="content">
        <a href="#" class="headerlogo"></a>
        <div class="headercontact">
            <ul class="headernumbers"></ul>
            <ul class="headersocial"></ul>
        </div>
        <nav id="mainnav">
            <ul class="nav"></ul>
       </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

Does it matter which way is used?

Comment: There's no standard for this.

Comment: It is up to you.. if you need more details  visit http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/nav and here  http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/sections.html#the-nav-element